# Seeding in Rails - check if a seed is needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't want to load a seed file for every deployment, since it takes 2-3 mins.
I only want to load the seeds if it is needed.

I have the following code which will run a seed in the initializer of the application, so when the application starts, it will load the seeds.  But is there a way to only do it if it is needed (i.e. something has changed?)

For migrations we have:  `if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?`
But what about seeds?

```
if ENV_PROPS['run_seeds_at_startup']
      Common::Log.info 'Starting seed load'
        seed_file = File.join('db/seeds.rb')
        load(seed_file) if File.exist?(seed_file)
      Common::Log.info 'Seed data loaded'
else
  Common::Log.info 'Automatic Seeds are shutdown in the env-props.yml...'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally if there's data I only need to create once, I try to setup a custom rake task that can either be run on the server directly post deploy, or one can setup a capistrano recipe to run it once. If you want to use seeds.rb, really the only way I've found to do this is to check if the records exist already. But i'm not aware of any global check or wrapper around executing the seeds file.

Comment: we have that, but we want to reduce manual steps.  Is there a way to check if the seed file is different, by using subversion in rails in code?

Comment: Not that im aware of, but really this requires very little manual work. You only have to create a capistrano task once. Update the rake task instead of the seed data as you need to change it. Do a deploy, then run that capistrano task.